# libreoffice Replace references inside long text using INDIRECT references

Tags: regex, replace, libreoffice-calc

I am puzzling how to replace references using formula inside a long text. For example:

```
A1: fox
A2: dog
A3: The quick brown REFA1 jumps over the lazy REFA2.
```

I want to have the result in A4. I tried REGEX with INDIRECT, but it doesn't work.

```
A4: =REGEX(A3 ;"REF([A-Z][:digit:]+)";INDIRECT("$1"); "g")
```

Libre executes INDIRECT before applying captured group and prints "#REF!" because "$1" is not legal reference.

P.S. Text in A3 is coming from another source and I cannot preformat it using string concatenation.

Comment: Write the correct cell addresses. The sample code (in the gray parts of the question) lists the cells in column A (A1:A4). And in the text of the question, used D1 instead of A4, in the formula used C1 instead of A3. This is very confusing - instead of thinking about the problem, we are think "what the author meant".

Comment: 2JohnSUN. Ups. Sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot come up with the correct formula for this task, then use the macro:

```
Function RefSubstitute(sSourceText As String, sRefPrefix As String, Optional sSourceSheet As Variant) As String 
Dim sTemp As Variant 
Dim oSheet As Variant 
Dim i As Long 
Dim sAddress As String, sSubst As String 
Dim FA As Variant, argSearch As Variant, argReplace As Variant
    RefSubstitute = sSourceText 
    If IsMissing(sSourceSheet) Then
        oSheet = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet()
    Else 
        If ThisComponent.getSheets().hasByName(sSourceSheet) Then 
            oSheet = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName(sSourceSheet)
        Else 
            RefSubstitute = "Wrong sheet name"
            Exit Function
        EndIf 
    EndIf 
    If InStr(sSourceText, sRefPrefix) = 0 Then 
        RefSubstitute = sSourceText 
        Exit Function 
    EndIf 
    FA = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    argSearch = Array("","^[A-Z][:digit:]+")
    argReplace = Array("","^[A-Z][:digit:]+","")
    sTemp = Split(sSourceText, sRefPrefix)
    For i = LBound(sTemp)+1 To UBound(sTemp)
        argSearch(0) = sTemp(i)
        sAddress = FA.callFunction("REGEX",argSearch)
        sSubst = ""
        On Error Resume Next 
            sSubst = oSheet. getCellRangeByName(sAddress).getCellByPosition(0, 0).getString()
        On Error GoTo 0
        argReplace(0) = sTemp(i)
        argReplace(2) = sSubst
        sTemp(i) = FA.callFunction("REGEX",argReplace)
    Next i
    RefSubstitute = Join(sTemp,"")
End Function
```

Call it like

```
=REFSUBSTITUTE(A3 ;"REF")
```

if all links point to the current sheet, or

```
=REFSUBSTITUTE(A3 ;"REF";"Sheet2")
```

if "fox" and "dog" on the another sheet